# Delete Rows Where Condition is Met? MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am looking at doing some deduping in MySQL but I want to only keep the record which has data in a specific field.

Table data looks like this.

CustomerID | First Name | Last Name | Last Purchase Date | + 10 other fields.

I want to find records which have the same customerID and delete the ones which do not have the Last Purchase Date. I've tried selecting the right data first before deleting like this but with no luck.

```
SELECT customerID, `Last Purchase Date` 
FROM `table 2` t1
    WHERE
     EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM `table 2` t2
        WHERE
          t2.customerID = t1.customerID
          AND `Last Purchase Date` = ''
      )
    ORDER BY customerID DESC;
```

Update: Here is a Fiddle with the data sample.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4743f/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the records which don't have a `Last Purchase Date`, because those are the ones you will be deleting. So...

```
SELECT t1.customerID, t1.`Last Purchase Date` 
FROM `table 2` t1
WHERE
    t1.`Last Purchase Date` = ''
    AND EXISTS (
            SELECT t2.customerID
            FROM `table 2` t2
            WHERE
                t2.customerID = t1.customerID
                AND t2.`Last Purchase Date` <> ''
        )
ORDER BY t1.customerID DESC;
```

For deletion, you would simply remove the `ORDER BY` clause, and replace `SELECT ... FROM` with `DELETE FROM`.

Comment: This seems good! I also added AND t1.customerID != ' ' after the first WHERE for Last Purchase Date as I also wanted to make sure blank CustomerID fields where not included in the search. 

This seems to have worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. You don't provide test data, so I can't readily check it. But the idea is to use what you're already doing, and add an extra check in the where clause.

```
SELECT customerID, `Last Purchase Date` 
FROM `table 2` t1
    WHERE
     EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM `table 2` t2
        WHERE
          t2.customerID = t1.customerID
          AND `Last Purchase Date` = ''
      ) AND t1.`Last Purchase Date` <> ''
    ORDER BY customerID DESC;
```